# CORS not working with zuul enabled gateway and swagger

Tags: java, spring-boot, cors, swagger-2.0, netflix-zuul

I am facing strange issue while setting up cors with my swagger gateway and operating on the zuul mechanism gateway has list of microservices. on the click of it will redirect to specific service swagger doc and when I using swagger "Try it out" functionality.
[This is how swagger gateway list looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UvgNN.png)

problem is that "Try it out" calling option method call to check cross origin operation and failing with 401.

For ex.

This is my swagger gateway url

```
abc.com/replica-stock/swagger-ui.html
```

and zuul converts it to following one

```
replica-stock.com/swagger-ui.html
```

and for the "Try it out" api check the URL is like this

```
xyz.com/api/v1/getStock
```

and I am getting following error in browser console

```
Access to fetch at 'xyz.com/api/v1/getStock' from origin 'abc.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
```

and this is my request and response headers look like

**Request header**

```
:method: OPTIONS
:path: /replica-stock/api/v1/replicaStocks/13?partCode=1234&usageCode=01
:scheme: https
accept: */*
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-IN,en-US;q=0.9,en-GB;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
access-control-request-headers: authorization
access-control-request-method: GET
origin: abc.com
referer: abc.com/replica-stock/swagger-ui.html
sec-fetch-dest: empty
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-site: same-site
```

**Response headers**

```
access-control-allow-credentials: true
access-control-allow-headers: authorization
access-control-allow-methods: GET
access-control-allow-origin: abc.com
allow: GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, TRACE, OPTIONS, PATCH
content-length: 0
content-type: application/json;charset=ISO-8859-1
date: Mon, 17 Aug 2020 06:16:20 GMT
status: 401
vary: Origin
vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
x-vcap-request-id: 2b52f4f7-085f-449e-5429-ffbd830cd5db
```

Can someone help me where I have to fix this cors issue ?

Comment: Check my answer in this post and try this config in your project. https://stackoverflow.com/a/63292799/13039704

Comment: As you mention you have a redirection to finish swagger endpoint. Second automate request Zuul make without authorization header. You can see it in logs if turn on security debug mode like this.  @EnableWebSecurity(debug = true) more info https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-registered-filters

Comment: Hey thanks for your explanation but the solution was to add the CORS at gateway and allow the CORS there!.