# Spring gateway swagger configuration CORS

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

I have two services: user service and logic service, and spring gateway to access them. Both of my services have spring security configured, that requires JWT token on some methods. On my logic microservice I configured `springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui` swagger dependency like this:

```
@Configuration
@SecurityScheme(
    name = "bearerAuth",
    type = SecuritySchemeType.HTTP,
    bearerFormat = "JWT",
    scheme = "bearer"
)
public class OpenApiConfiguration {

}
```

And then added on my controllers (note that `CrossOrigin` already here):

```
@CrossOrigin
@SecurityRequirement(name = "bearerAuth")
public class LogicController {
...
}
```

In swagger I can see what paths are protected, what not. And I can call them with valid JWT token, it's all works just fine from microservice swagger directly. The problem is with spring gateway swagger. I configured paths like this:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      default-filters:
        - DedupeResponseHeader=Access-Control-Allow-Credentials Access-Control-Allow-Origin
      globalcors:
        corsConfigurations:
          '[/**]':
            allowedOrigins: "*"
            allowedMethods: "*"
            allowedHeaders: "*"
      routes:
        - id: logic-service
          uri: lb://LOGIC-SERVICE
          predicates:
            - Path=/api/logic/**
        - id: user-manager
          uri: lb://USER-MANAGER
          predicates:
            - Path=/user-manager/**
            - Path=/other-api/**
        - id: logic-service-swagger
          uri: lb://LOGIC-SERVICE
          predicates:
            - Path=/logic/v3/api-docs
        - id: user-manager-swagger
          uri: lb://USER-MANAGER
          predicates:
            - Path=/user/v3/api-docs

springdoc:
  api-docs:
    enabled: true
  swagger-ui:
    enabled: true
    path: /swagger-ui.html
    config-url: /v3/api-docs/swagger-config
    urls:
      - url: /logic/v3/api-docs
        name: Logic service
      - url: /user/v3/api-docs
        name: Users service
```

I'm using these dependencies on my gateway:

```
 <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
      <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webflux-ui</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>
    </dependency>
 <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Swagger paths are correct, I can open the gateway swagger and choose between 2 of my services, Eureka is working, services are registered, this is not a problem. I can perform public methods, but can't call methods that are secured with token. The requests from gateway swagger are getting sent with correct authorization header. As I said same request is working on the swagger microservice directly.
For example, if I open logic microservice swagger on `8081` port, click on `authorize` button in swagger and perform request, it's working fine. But when I do the same on `8080` gateway port, it's giving me cors error:

```
Failed to fetch.
Possible Reasons:
CORS
Network Failure
URL scheme must be "http" or "https" for CORS request.
```

The curl that is getting generated is the same both on logic microservice swagger and on gateway swagger, i.e. even from gateway swagger the curl generated is using `8081` port of logic microservice. But it was working fine before I added JWT security configuraton to the logic service. If I make a generated curl call to both `8080` (gateway) and `8081` (directly), they both send me a normal response (the same curl is working if I change port to `8080` i.e. gateway port):

```
curl -X 'GET' \
  'http://localhost:8081/api/logic/...' \
  -H 'accept: */*' \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer token...'
```

I already tried to add this, as it was suggested in another answer:

```
default-filters:
        - DedupeResponseHeader=Access-Control-Allow-Credentials Access-Control-Allow-Origin
      globalcors:
        corsConfigurations:
          '[/**]':
            allowedOrigins: "*"
            allowedMethods: "*"
            allowedHeaders: "*"
```

But it's not working. Setting level to debug on gateway also doesn't help, nothing is getting logged. Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so turns out you also need to add `cors` in security configuration on microservice itself:

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .cors().and()
                .csrf().disable()
                ...;
    }
```

Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63291025/spring-boot-app-return-access-to-xmlhttprequest-at-myurl-has-been-blocked-by-c)